# AngularJS filter in js file declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know what is the best way to declare a filter using it from a js.

My app.js looks like this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('kk', [
        'lib1',
        'lib2',
        'lib3'
    ])
})();
```

I've saw in some webpages declaring it appending to `angular.module(...).filter('filterName', function()...)` but, how about "inject" from a js file?

I've been trying with:

```
.filter('filterName', 'path/to/customFilter.js');
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT with SOLUTION**

Using @Torben approach and making it slightly cleaner, my solution (just in case for anyone):

1. Make the reference into index.html `<script src="path/to/CustomFilter.js"></script>`
2. Let app.js as is, without anyfilter references
3. Create code `CustomFilter.js`
4. Inside filterName.js `angular.module('kk').filter('customFilter', CustomFilter.js);`

Example of CustomerFilter.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function CustomFilter() {
        return function(input) {
            return something;
        };
    };
    angular.module('kk').filter('customFilter', CustomFilter);
})();
```

Example of usage

```
<div>{{ input | customFilter }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML file write

```
<script src="path/to/customFilter.js'"></script>
```

Then it is included. Your `customFilter.js` should start with

```
angular.module(...).filter('filterName', function()...)
```

as you already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Torben, but the idea is to avoid the function istself in app.js, just a declaration. What should I put in that `function()...`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I read it wrong. Anyway, my idea is to keep all the declarations of controller, services, ... in app.js. Is it possible?

Comment: Defintively I agree with your solution. Thanks!